# subview background color not animating

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uianimation

I have a `UIViewController` that contains a subview that renders a waveform. When a button is pressed, I'm trying to get the main `UIView`, the subview, and the navigation bar to change from white to gray. I've been able to get the main view and navigation bar to change, but can't figure out how to get the subview with the waveform to change. Right now the subview instantly changes to gray rather than animating in sync with the other view and navigation bar.

```
//View Controller Code

UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, animations: {

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 20.00/255, green: 20.00/255, blue: 20.00/255, alpha: 1.00)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.waveform.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 20.00/255, green: 20.00/255, blue: 20.00/255, alpha: 1.00)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 20.00/255, green: 20.00/255, blue: 20.00/255, alpha: 1.00)

    }, completion: { finished in

         //do stuff
 })

//waveform view

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    for i in 0..<self.circles.count {
        self.draw(self.circles[i], ratio: -1.0)
        self.draw(self.circles[i], ratio: 1.0)
    }
}

func update(_ level: Double) {

    amplitude = fmin(normalizedPowerLevelFromDecibels(level), maxAmplitude)
    setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

//Updated animation

```
UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration: 1.0, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 20.00/255, green: 20.00/255, blue: 20.00/255, alpha: 1.00)


    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 20.00/255, green: 20.00/255, blue: 20.00/255, alpha: 1.00)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()

    self.waveform.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 20.00/255, green: 20.00/255, blue: 20.00/255, alpha: 1.00)

}, completion: nil)
```

This causes the waveform view and navigation bar to animate in sync, but `self.view` changes to dark gray instantly after the two other views are done animating...

Comment: Can't get an idea from above chunk of code can you please share your project with arunjos007@gmail.com then I will try to figure out the problem

Comment: Friend are you setting initial color ?

Comment: I have tried your code it is working fine. Colours are animating for all three...

Comment: @Mukesh I don't set the background color anywhere until I try to animate it to gray. Its default white in storyboard

Comment: I have updated answer, that block of code always working for me.

Answer (score 0):

My idea of doing animation is like this

**Objective-C**

```
//Set Initial frame or color here & then write block for animation

 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{

      // Now set your changing animation frame or color here

    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        //Do completion stuff here

    }];
```

If you are going to set it by `anyView.layer.backgroundColor` then `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

**Swift**

```
//Set Initial frame or color here & then write block for animation

UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {

      // Now set your changing animation frame or color here
      self.view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 20.00/255, green: 20.00/255, blue: 20.00/255, alpha: 1.00).cgColor

}, completion: { finished in

            //do completion stuffs
    })
```

If you are going to set it by `anyView.layer.backgroundColor` then `import QuartzCore`

Comment: my subview isn't just a UIview i added through interface builder. its customized and programmatically created.

Comment: can you try it with `.layer` ?

Comment: With `.layer` the view doesnt change colors at all.

Comment: very strange .. its also working in the my project. I think you are doing something wrong on different place, Send your project mukesh.lokare1@gmail.com i will try to figure out issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in:-

```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options:[.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
        self.view1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 20.00/255, green: 20.00/255, blue: 20.00/255, alpha: 1.00)
        self.view2.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 20.00/255, green: 20.00/255, blue: 20.00/255, alpha: 1.00)

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 26.00/255, green: 152.00/255, blue: 143.00/255, alpha: 1.00)


        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 20.00/255, green: 20.00/255, blue: 20.00/255, alpha: 1.00)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Ok this kind of works. I made some adjustments. I left `with: self.view` the same. Under animations I'm changing the backgrounds of `self.view`, `self.waveform`, and `self.navigationController?.navigationBar`. I'm not using `.layer`. Now the navigation bar and the waveform view animate in sync, but the main view changes instantly to gray after both the waveform and navigation bar have already animated to gray.

Comment: Is your main view is gray already? Try to set different (may be white) color before animation and then set background color to gray. Increase animation time and do all this stuff in viewDidAppear()

Comment: No the main view is already white. It turns gray instantly, while the other views animate. Do the animations in `ViewDidAppear()`? Why? This all occurs after a button is pressed.

Comment: Ok then please update code what your are doing in method?

Comment: @Brosef see my updated ans and put your view code in it. Its working for me in test project.

Answer (score 0):

So the waveform view background color can't be animated because of my implementation of `drawRect`. What I had to do was to set the background color to the waveform view to clear, then add another `UIView` behind it and animate the background color of that view.